# Typescript: enforce object values without losing explicit keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In the following example, I'm able to extract explicit keys from the object, but i'm unable to enforce its values

```js
const myCollection = {
    a: {test: 1},
    b: {test: 2},
    c: {text: 3} // no error
};

type MyCollectionKeys = keyof typeof myCollection;
// MyCollectionKeys is 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
```

When enforcing the values using the following snippet, you lose explicit keys:

```js
type CollectionValue = {test: number};

const myCollection: ({[k: string]: CollectionValue}) = {
    a: {test: 1},
    b: {test: 2},
    c: {text: 3} // Type '{ text: number; }' is not assignable to type 'CollectionValue'.
};

type MyCollectionKeys = keyof typeof myCollection;
// MyCollectionKeys is string | number
```

A workaround I found is to proxy the object like so:

```js
type CollectionValue = {test: number};

const _myCollection = {
    a: {test: 1},
    b: {test: 2},
    c: {text: 3}
};

type MyCollectionKeys = keyof typeof _myCollection;
// MyCollectionKeys is 'a' | 'b' | 'c'

const myCollection: ({[k in MyCollectionKeys]: CollectionValue}) = _myCollection;
// Type '{ a: { test: number; }; b: { test: number; }; c: { text: number; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ a: CollectionValue; b: CollectionValue; c: CollectionValue; }'.
//  Types of property 'c' are incompatible.
//    Property 'test' is missing in type '{ text: number; }' but required in type 'CollectionValue'
```

The drawbacks of this method are:

- you must have a proxy object
- if you violate the type, the error is thrown at the assignment instead of being thrown inside the original object at the offending key

Is there a more elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately generics cannot be partially inferred from use, so in this case i would probably just enumerate the valid keys:

```
const myCollection: Record<'a' | 'b' | 'c', { test: number }> = {
    a: {test: 1},
    b: {test: 2},
    c: {text: 3} // error
};
```

If you do not mind introducing a pointless function:

```
const check = <T extends string>(collection: Record<T, { test: number }>) => collection;

const myCollection = check({
    a: {test: 1},
    b: {test: 2},
    c: {text: 3} // error
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid enumerating the keys myself as it is tedious.  
I'll give the function a try, as it will only run once at init and it's mostly a noop

Comment: the function approach looks nice, and you can even make it generic:
`export function assertObjectRecordIntegrity<T>() {
  return <Keys extends string>(object: Record<Keys, T>) => object;
}
`